# Using jQuery filter() to get all matched .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of textfields and I need to select the values of those textfields whose values are not equal to their `title` attribute.

**Problem:** With my attempt, the jQuery code below simply selects the value of the first matched textfield. How do I get all matched textfields' values?

**jQuery Code**

```
var inputs = $(".input").filter(function() {
                return $(this).val() != $(this).attr('title');
            }).val();
console.log(inputs);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is simpler solution:

```
var input = [];
jQuery('input[type=text]').each(function(){
   if(jQuery(this).val() != jQuery(this).attr('title') ) {
   input.push(jQuery(this).val());
   }
});
```

Comment: With this method, it seems not to store the textfield values in the array, but stored the HTML of the matched DOM elements... do you get that too?

Comment: No, i've tested this solution, and as you see i'm obviously pushing value into array

Answer (score 3):

The `.val()` method only returns the value of the first element in the selected list of elements. Try turning it into an array instead:

```
var inputs = $(".input").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() != $(this).attr('title');
}).map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
console.log(inputs);
```

Comment: is the `.get()` chained to the end required? I tried with and without chaining the `.get()` and got the same results in Chrome's developer console...

Comment: It is, and it isn't. jQuery objects are technically arrays, but they contain additional properties and methods that you may not need. Using `.get()` turns it into a native array rather than a jQuery object containing an array of strings.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var inputs = [];
$(".input").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() != $(this).attr('title');
}).each(function() {
    inputs.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(inputs);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/cCRfE/

Comment: Thanks! I tried using arrays and pushing them initially, but couldnt get it done without realizing that `.each()` will be useful for doing so.